# Return data to select component dropdown in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm working with ngx-select-dropdown (https://github.com/manishjanky/ngx-select-dropdown) and I want to return the list of Cities in an array of objects to show them in a select menu dropdown autocomplete. But I can't return any data. 
this is my html:

```
<ngx-select-dropdown id="id_city" name="id_city"
   (change)="selectionChanged($event)" 
   [multiple]="false" 
   [(ngModel)]="filters.idCity" 
   [config]="config" 
   [options]="cityFilterList">
</ngx-select-dropdown>
```

and my component.ts

```
getAllCities() {
    this.cityService.getAllCities(this.filters.dataBase, 0).subscribe(
        response => {
            this.cityFilterList = (response.Data ? response.Data : []);
        },
        error => {
            console.log('Error!');
        }
    );
}
```

These are how my data should be return:

```
[
{id: 1, city: 'London', id_unity: 'L001'},
{id: 2, city: 'Leicester', id_unity: 'L002'},
{id: 2, city: 'Leicester', id_unity: 'L003'}
]
```

And cityFilterList is declared as any:[];

Answer (score 0):

As of now ngx-select-dropdown uses Default change detection startegy which means dirty checking checks for immutable data types. And in Javascript Objects and arrays are mutable. So when changing any of the @Input parameters if you mutate an object change detection will not detect it. For ex:-

```
 this.cityFilterList = (response.Data ? response.Data : []);
```

above code will not trigger the change detection. In order for the componet to detect the changes what you need to do is:-

```
 this.cityFilterList = (response.Data ? [...response.Data] : []);
```

Comment: Can you create an example with similar issue on stackblitz?